# Variable not replacing value in loop in R

Tags: r, loops, variables

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a large excel sheet I'm importing to R.
2. The data needs to be cleaned so one of the procedures is to test for character length.
3. Once the program finds a string that is too long, it needs to prompt the operator for a replacement
4. The operator inputs an alternative, and the program replaces the original with the input text.

The code I have seems to work procedurally, but the variable I have is not overwriting the original value.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(readxl)
fileToOpen <-read_excel(file.choose(),sheet="Data")
MasterFile <- fileToOpen

#This line checks the remaining bad strings in the column
CPNErrors <- nrow(filter(MasterFile,nchar(Field_to_Check) > 26))

#This line selects the bad field from the first in the list of strings to exceed the limit
TEST <- select(filter(MasterFile,nchar(Field_to_Check) > 26),Field_to_Check)[1,]

#This is the loop -- prompts the operator for a replacement, assigns a variable to the input and then replaces the bad value in the data frame

while (CPNErrors >= 1) {message("Replace ",TEST," with what?"); var=readline();MasterFile$Field_to_Check[MasterFile$Field_to_Check == TEST] <- var;print(var)}
```

The prompt works and assigns the readline() to the var, but the code will not replace the original string as a variable.  When I run the code separately outside the loop, it will replace as long as I input an exact string (no variable assignment), so there's some syntactical thing I'm missing.

I've been searching for hours, and am just starting out in R, so if anyone can offer any assistance I'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT -- ok... I think I found the source of the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.  When I run

```
MasterFile$Field_to_Check[MasterFile$Field_to_Check == TEST]
```

It comes with a null result, but if I run

```
MasterFile$Field_to_Check[MasterFile$Field_to_Check == "Some Text that's in the data frame"]
```

It comes out with a result.  Any idea on why I can't filter this list by the variable?  The TEST variable comes out as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with a `for` loop :

```
CPNErrors <- which(nchar(MasterFile$Field_to_Check) > 26)

for(i in CPNErrors){
  var=readline(paste0("Replace ",MasterFile$Field_to_Check[i]," with what? "))
  MasterFile$Field_to_Check[i] <- var
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work.  It does assign the variable, but like my other code, it doesn't actually replace the bad data in the original data frame.  :(

Comment: @J.Alexander When I checked my answer on a sample dataframe of my own it works for me. Can you provide sample of your data with `dput(head(MasterFile, 10))` for me to test the answer on your dataset?

Comment: Good lord.  I don't know what I did wrong the first time -- I razed the code down and restarted and used your code block and it worked like a charm.  Can't thank you enough!!